# Hacer un asset en Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hola hay alguna forma de poner el asset de Laravel en un jquery?

```
$( ".menuullia2" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.menuContacto').css("content","url('../images/svg/phone-call2.svg')");
    $('.menuContacto').css("transition","1s");
});
```

Si subo de nivel desde la raiz no carga la imagen.

Comment: Si tienes el archivo en tu carpeta public, entonces no habría problema en acceder a dicho archivo

Comment: pero hace falta hacer un asset?? @L.Flor

Comment: Si la ruta completa de tu archivo es `public/images/svg/phone-call2.svg`, entonces sólo accedes así `images/svg/phone-call2.svg`. Lo has intentado así y no obtienes resultados?

Comment: Lo he probado pero sucede lo mismo, el archivo donde hago los javascript es en esta ruta `public/js/archivo.js` y la ruta de la imagen si es esta `public/images/svg/phone-call2.svg, entonces sólo accedes así images/svg/phone-call2.svg`  @L.Flor

Comment: `/images/svg/phone-call2.svg`

Comment: Ok ok!! ahora si que funciona, solo por esa slash??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera correcta de acceder a un archivo dentro de tu folder `public` es de la siguiente manera (absolute path):

```
/images/svg/phone-call2.svg
```

Omitir el backslash al inicio del path (relative path) hará que busque un folder llamado `images` dentro de `public/js/`(Desde donde haces el llamado), el cual no existe.